# Auth($this->auth->login()) return false in cakephp 2.5.6

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.5

$this->auth->login() always returns false.

I must use model PintiplanAutore model

in my view correctly displays the sql query

SELECT `PintiplanAutore`.`idautor`, `PintiplanAutore`.`idfacebook`, `PintiplanAutore`.`nombre`, `PintiplanAutore`.`correo`, `PintiplanAutore`.`password`, `PintiplanAutore`.`token`, `PintiplanAutore`.`imagen`, `PintiplanAutore`.`rol` FROM `pintiplan`.`pintiplan_autores` AS `PintiplanAutore` WHERE `PintiplanAutore`.`correo` = 'aa@aa.com' LIMIT 1

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('PintiplanAutore',array('action'=>'login'));
    echo $this->Form->input('correo');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');

?>
<?php echo $this->Session->flash('auth'); ?>
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

appController.php

```
<?php App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
class AppController extends Controller {
public $components=array(
'Session',
'Auth' => array(


        'authenticate'=>array(
            'Form'=>array(
                'userModel'=>'PintiplanAutore',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'correo',
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                    )
                )
            )

        )
);


public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Auth->allow('index','verSitio','sitiosPublicos','verSitiosPlan','planesPublicos');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'PintiplanAutores','action'=>'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'Nosotros', 'action' => 'index');
}
```

}

PintiplanAutoresController.php

```
<?php
   App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
   class PintiplanAutoresController extends AppController {
      public $components = array('Paginator', 'Session');
      public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        // Allow users to register and logout.
        $this->Auth->allow('add','logout','login');
    }

public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->PintiplanAutore->create();
        if ($this->PintiplanAutore->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The pintiplan autore has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The pintiplan autore could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
}
public function login(){

        if ($this->request->is('post')){
            //echo debug($this->request->data['PintiplanAutore']['password']);
            debug($this->Auth->login()); die();


        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'Nosotros', 'action' => 'index'));
            //return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }

        $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));

        }
    }
 ?>
```

Model PintiplanAutore:

```
<?php
   App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
   App::uses('BlowfishPasswordHasher', 'Controller/Component/Auth');
   class PintiplanAutore extends AppModel {
     public $primaryKey = 'idautor';
       public $validate = array(
       'nombre' => array(
           'required' => array(
               'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
               'message' => 'A username is required'
           )
       ),
        'correo' => array(
           'required' => array(
               'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
               'message' => 'A correo is required'
           )
       ),
       'password' => array(
           'required' => array(
               'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
               'message' => 'A password is required'
           )
       ),
       'rol' => array(
           'valid' => array(
               'rule' => array('inList', array('admin', 'author')),
               'message' => 'Please enter a valid role',
               'allowEmpty' => false
           )
       )
   );
    public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) {
        $passwordHasher = new BlowfishPasswordHasher();
        $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = $passwordHasher->hash(
            $this->data[$this->alias]['password']
        );
    }
    return true;
    }
   }
```

put my user with the action add

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

try with it

```
$user=$this->PintiplanAutore->findByCorreoAndPassword($yourCorreo_field_getting_from_form);

if($this->Auth->login($user)){

}
```

Comment: this works: $user = $this->PintiplanAutore->find('first',array(
                                        'conditions'=>array('$yourCorreo_field_getting_from_form,$yourPassword_field_getting_from_form)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me without making a query:

```
if($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)) { ... }
```